# Filling an arraycollection's array with objects from database

Tags: .net, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am new to `Flex` and am looking for something like this:

```
    <fx:Array>

        <fx:Object name="Jodie" country="UK" language="English"/>

        <fx:Object name="Kate" country="USA" language="English"/>

        <fx:Object name="David" country="France" language="French"/>

    </fx:Array>
```

But I want to do this dynamically from results that I get from a `DB`.
I have an attendance program and I want the object's names to be "Date","In","Out"
and the values to be, of course from the results that I get.

any pointers?

Comment: how are you getting the result from the db now? XML, AMF?

Comment: XML i receive from a web service using the WSDL protocol.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you do your research before this? What's the xml like? Show your code, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

SomeWebservice.lastResult.node <= is a collection already (kinda handy) since you are dealing with an object collection you can just iterate directly through it.

Obviously your XML layout would vary greatly depending on use and need.

You can use something like:

```
for each (var item:Object in GetSingleDashBoardCanvasItem.lastResult.DashboardItem)
                {
```

In this example my return type is E4X so the first "node" does not apply.

The XML would look like:

```
  <myData>
   <DashBoardItem>  <== is like a "recordset"
         <DashboardID>22</DashboardID>
     <DashboardName>Marketing</DashboardName>
    <somevalue>22</someValue>
    </DashBoardItem>
   <DashBoardItem>  <== is like a "recordset"
         <DashboardID>56</DashboardID>
     <DashboardName>Some Other Name</DashboardName>
    <somevalue>42</someValue>
    </DashBoardItem>
   <DashBoardItem>  <== is like a "recordset"
         <DashboardID></DashboardID>
     <DashboardName></DashboardName>
    <somevalue></someValue>
    </DashBoardItem>
  </myData>
```

You could just address an item directly if you know its a single return.

You can also just run casts on service replies:

```
someList.dataProvider='{new XMLListCollection(XMLList(GetDashReportList.lastResult).ReportTemplate)}'
```

The above is where I have simply decided to use a reply to populate a list.

Note that if your xml structure is correct. You can use this to overload values which is handy, in said list box I can now get selectedItem.AnyXMLNodeInTheRecordIwant  <= handy for multiple properties.

Etc. Etc you get the idea.

Comment: 10x for ur answers but I still haven't found what I'm looking for. The reason I need to dynamically add items to the array in the arraycollection is to use it as a data provider for an advanced datagrid and there, to group the dates so that each day will contain its attendance hours and be expandable by click. The thing is, I already can get the data i want from the DB and to use it as an arraycollection but I don't know how to use this data in a way I could group it. the code I posted showed how to hard code fields and assign data to them, how do i do this with the data i got from the db?

Comment: Ahh yes, in fact I can do one better for you.

I built dynamic data grids from data and population of said grids is a pain in the ass. 

One second... *scrounges his project for code snipper ** insert elevator music...

And here you go:

Answer (score 0):

public function xmlLoadCompleteAudit(evt:Event):void
{
    // This function is part of the Report Create and dynamically factors a Datagrid to represent any table returned regardless of its schema.
    //Alert.show(getViewPreview.lastResult.List.Record[0].ImageName);

```
try{


    xmlList = XML(getAuditTrail.lastResult).children();
    var dgCols:Array = new Array();

    AuditGrid.columns = dgCols;
    var xmlColumns:XMLList = xmlList[0].children();
    //Alert.show(xmlColumns.length());



    for(var x:uint=0; x < xmlColumns.length(); x++){
        var xml:XML = xmlColumns[x];

        var col:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
        if (xml.name() != 'Xlabel') 
        {
            //Alert.show(xml.attribute("myField"));
            col.headerText = xml.attribute("myField");
            col.dataField = xml.name();
            dgCols.push(col);
        }
    }
    AuditGrid.columns = dgCols;                           
    AuditGrid.dataProvider = xmlList;


}catch(e:Error){
```

Comment: Its worth mentioning that I came up with a custom xml schema to achieve this (See earlier comments.)

The use of Cdata tags can also not be stressed enough.

Comment: <field1 myfield="The Field Name">the value in the field in the db</field1>

field increments

Comment: If your wondering why the strange layout, remember grids behaviour in a column logic not a row logic as per record sets ;)

Comment: 10q Craig for the informative answer accompanied by the wonderful elevator music :) but I'm afraid I'm at a loss. I'll explain: when I used a regular datagrid. I used the following code: <s:DataGrid id="EmployeeDataGrid"
    width="100%" height="100%"
    selectionMode="singleRow"
    dataProvider="{EmployeesArr.Employees}">
 <s:columns>
   <s:ArrayList>
    <s:GridColumn dataField="Name" headerText="Name"/>
    <s:GridColumn dataField="Id" headerText="Id"/>
   </s:ArrayList>
 </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid> and everything worked fine. the EmployeesArr.Employees is an array that holds objects

Comment: each object has a Name:string and an Id:string and the regular grid displays the data as it should. now the problem with the advanced datagrid is that it received the same data but fails to group it properly so I don't see anything on it.

Comment: <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myADG" 
       width="100%" height="100%" 
       initialize="gc.refresh();">        
  <mx:dataProvider>
   <mx:GroupingCollection2 id="gc" source="{EmployeesArr.Employees}">
    <mx:grouping>
     <mx:Grouping>
      <mx:GroupingField name="Name"/>
     </mx:Grouping>
    </mx:grouping>
   </mx:GroupingCollection2>
  </mx:dataProvider>        
  
  <mx:columns>
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Name"/>
   <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="Id"/>
  </mx:columns>
 </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

Comment: because i use the "Name" datafield to group data I made sure I have employees with the same name but still I don't see any results on my advanced datagrid

Comment: ok I am with you, to make it work in your context, simple iterate through the lastResult object into an Array (ala push).

And then you will have your array. Or you could build many arrays.

My approach was aimed at just format my xml in the way that best suited my application, then use OLAP features to define what was what (in terms of grouping.) But I digress.

For what you need just drive through the result collection into your array.

Any reason your not using the Spark implementation is this Flex 3? or 4 or 4.5?

Comment: I should have warned that my code was I admit also designed to handle the fact that I had no idea how many columns I might get or even what they are.

It was used to preview data from a database in a BI tool. Thus it had to handle anything that was thrown at it. (indeterminate everything for a little extra fun in a morning).

its a generic

Comment: I would also check to see if EmployeesArr.Employees.Name resolves correctly

Comment: I'm using flex 4.5 and when I looked for examples of datagrid that enables me to expand its rows all I saw was examples of the mx:advanceddatagrid and the fields were all hard-coded. I've tried something a little different, I removed the <mx:dataProvider> part and I see the grid displays the data properly so it all boils down to the section <mx:dataProvider> which in it I'm supposed to group my data.

Comment: Looking at this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bf4.html it should be possible.

Provided said arrayCollections are well formed.